# /etc/udev directory not present in Docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, stm32

I am trying to use STM32CubeProgrammer within Ubuntu 20.04 inside Docker container. As a step to prepare USB serial link for flashing as given in [STM32CubeProgrammer](https://wiki.st.com/stm32mpu/wiki/STM32CubeProgrammer#STM32CubeProgrammer_overview) I need to do:

```
cd <your STM32CubeProgrammer install directory>/Drivers/rules
sudo cp *.* /etc/udev/rules.d/
```

But `/etc/udev/` directory is not available.

Is it safe to create this directory to access USB devices and what files should be part of this directory?

Comment: A Docker container won't usually have access to host devices, and it won't be running the tools necessary for Linux subsystems like udev.  This task will be much easier to run outside a container.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when creating a kinect4azure Docker image. I fixed it by installing the udev package.

```
sudo apt -y install udev
```

after that lsusb also gave more info about the connected usb devices.